# How to customize style of Bing maps in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bing-maps, bing

I want to set an "inverse" theme in bing maps for wpf (dark maps with white text). There's a property named "MapForegroundStyle", but I have no idea where to begin.

Any tips about this?

Comment: I don't think that style affects the coloring. I think it only determines where the copyright and logo positions are. The `Mode` property affects how it is displayed as it grabs different tiles or alternatively you use a different tile layer. I don't think there is what you need out of the box, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to do this in the WPF control. The MapForegroundStyle is for controls that are overlaid on top of the map, such as the Bing logo and the scale bars.